# Is it possible to overlay a background image with another image and make the overlaying image transparent?

Tags: css, sass

here is my css with the 2 background images:

```
.hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd3 {
        //height: 749px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        background: url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_overlay_bkgrnd2.jpg),  
        url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_bkgrnd2.png);
        background-size: 30%, 100%; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: center 50%, center;
            
      }
```

this works great except I would like the top image to have some transparency so that the bottom image can still be seen through the top image.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way of forcing an image to have transparency through CSS alone. The image itself would have to specify the alpha channel for the pixels you wanted transparent.

Comment: There's (at least) a couple of - differently-imperfect - ways to achieve something *like* this, but one involves changing the image's transparency/opacity directly, and the other involves using an `<img>` above the background.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't certain but it never hurts to ask. i can see if my designer can design the image differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode). It will blend/overlap both images and in a certain way create "transparency". Depending on the actual output you intend to have it might do the trick.

The following example uses `multiply` but there are many other blend modes you can try, depending on your images might work better.

```css
.hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd3 {
  height: 749px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  background: url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_overlay_bkgrnd2.jpg), url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_bkgrnd2.png);
  background-blend-mode: multiply; /* <- use any blend mode here */
  background-size: 30%, 100%; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: center 50%, center;          
}
```

Run the following snippet to try-out the different blend-modes:

```js
const blendEl = document.getElementById("blend");
const backgroundBlend = document.querySelector('.backgroundBlend')
var selectedBlend;

function onChange(e) {
  if (selectedBlend) backgroundBlend.classList.remove(selectedBlend);

  selectedBlend = blendEl.value;
  backgroundBlend.classList.add(selectedBlend);
}

blendEl.onchange = onChange;
onChange();
```

```css
.backgroundBlend {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/200/300/200'), url('https://picsum.photos/id/201/300/200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.imageA {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/200/300/200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.imageB {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/201/300/200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.normal {
  background-blend-mode: normal;
}

.multiply {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.screen {
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}

.overlay {
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
}

.darken {
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}

.lighten {
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.color-dodge {
  background-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}

.color-burn {
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.hard-light {
  background-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.soft-light {
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}

.difference {
  background-blend-mode: difference;
}

.exclusion {
  background-blend-mode: exclusion;
}

.hue {
  background-blend-mode: hue;
}

.saturation {
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
}

.color {
  background-blend-mode: color;
}

.luminosity {
  background-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="backgroundBlend">
    <select id="blend">
      <option value="normal" selected>normal</option>
      <option value="multiply" selected>multiply</option>
      <option value="screen">screen</option>
      <option value="overlay">overlay</option>
      <option value="darken">darken</option>
      <option value="lighten">lighten</option>
      <option value="color-dodge">color-dodge</option>
      <option value="color-burn">color-burn</option>
      <option value="hard-light">hard-light</option>
      <option value="soft-light">soft-light</option>
      <option value="difference">difference</option>
      <option value="exclusion">exclusion</option>
      <option value="hue">hue</option>
      <option value="saturation">saturation</option>
      <option value="color">color</option>
      <option value="luminosity">luminosity</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="imageA"></div>
  <div class="imageB"></div>
</div>
```